# Можно ли получить название роли, которая отсутствует для метода контроллера?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Имеем вот такой контроллер

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER_READ')")
method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/{id}"
public ResponseEntity<?> getById(@PathVariable String id) {
    User user = userRepository.findOne(id);
    if (user != null)
        return ResponseEntity.ok(user);
    else
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(new ErrorResponse("Пользователь не найден"));
}
```

и класс, реализующий интерфейс **AccessDeniedHandler**

```
public class AccessDeniedHandlerImpl implements AccessDeniedHandler {
 
    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException, ServletException {
 
        request.setAttribute(WebAttributes.ACCESS_DENIED_403, accessDeniedException);
 
        request.getRequestURL();
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
 
        response.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().printf("{ \"error\": \"Недостаточно права\"}");
        response.getWriter().flush();
 
    }
}
```

Можно ли достать в классе **AccessDeniedHandlerImpl** получить в данном случае **USER_READ**

Comment: Зачем ведь она уже есть?

Comment: Роль есть у контроллера, а вот в AccessDeniedHandler её нет

Comment: Если нет, то можно поставить. В чем вопрос?

Comment: "Можно ли получить роль в AccessDeniedHandlerImpl", я как бы не нашёл как, но думал, что тут люди могли знать

Comment: Мы здесь отвечаем на какие попало вопросы, это не форум, где люди высказывают все что знают. Если не согласен, то почитай правила [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Вопрос составлен корректно. "Мы здесь отвечаем на какие попало вопросы" это я уже понял. Я не прошу чьё-то мнение, я прошу конкретного ответа, можно ли получить право, которого нет при вызове метода контроллера. И да, это не правила, а рекомендации

Comment: Наверно ты не понял, *правильный* ответ дать невозможно если вопрос поставлен таким образом как у тебя. И я стараюсь, а тебе рекомендую, придерживаться этих правил. Ответы типа "да" или "нет" нельзя сохранить в качестве ответа, а писать код за тебя вряд ли кто-то будет. Поэтому пускай закрывают вопрос за отсутствием деталей.